# pip configuration go wrong after ubuntu restart

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, jupyter-notebook

after restart my ubuntu 16.04, could not find pip

I can only get my original pip via `python3 -m pip freeze`

if I use `pip freeze` there shows `bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory`

And I installed my `jupyter` via `pip install` and I could not use `jupyter notebook` command now. It shows `jupyter: command not found`

And I make sure I use `sudo apt-get update` and when I want to install a new jupyter with `sudo apt-get install jupyter-notebook` it shows

```
E: Unable to locate package jupyter-notebook
```

Seems **several system configuration go wrong**? How to recover these? How can I open my jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

> bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory

Verify the file `/usr/bin/pip` exists. If it does check the first line:

```
head -1 /usr/bin/pip
```

The line (called [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))) must be something like `#!/usr/bin/python`. If it isn't edit the file and fix the shebang line to point to an existing `python` binary.

> I installed my jupyter via `pip install` and I could not use `jupyter notebook` command now. It shows `jupyter: command not found`

It's because `pip` installed `jupyter` into a directory not in `$PATH`. Most probably `/usr/local/bin/`. Check the directory with `pip show --files jupyter` and add the directory to your `$PATH` both in the current shell and in your `~/.bash_profile`.

> I want to install a new jupyter with `sudo apt-get install jupyter-notebook` it shows `E: Unable to locate package jupyter-notebook`

Try `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: 1) The file `/usr/bin/pip` does not exist, but command `python3 -m pip` would give my previous correct pip. 2) I made sure I tried `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install jupyter-notebook` but still unable to locate package

Answer (score 0):

The pip problem has been solved.

The reason is that `PATH` is somehow modified and it loses the `~/.local/bin`, the original pip is in this path and pip also install jupyter notebook in this path.

After I added `~/.local/bin` to `PATH` I can run pip and jupyter notebook, in brief this is a `path` problem